# How to create an event calender in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

How to create an event calendar in Flutter like google calender to add appointments and events?

[image: Calendar like this]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin, may help with that: https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar